# Import multiple .txt files into R and skip to actual data rows

Tags: r, import

I have 537 .txt files which I need to import into either a list or separate data frames in R. I do not want to append any data as it is crucial to keep everything separate.

I've renamed each file, so the file names are all uniform. In each file, there is a header section with a lot of miscellaneous information. This header section is 12-16 rows depending on the file. For the data, I have between 5 and 7 columns. The data is all tab delimited. The number of columns varies between 5 and 9 columns, and the columns are not always in the same order, so it is important that I can import the column names with the data (column names are uniform across files). The format of the file is as follows:

Header

Header

Header

Header...up to 16 rows

((number of spaces between header and column names varies))

Date(\t)Time(\t)dataCol1(\t)dataCol2(\t)dataCol3(\t)dataCol4

((no  empty row between column names and units))

mm/dd/yyyy(\t)hh:mm:ss(\t)units(\t)units(\t)units(\t)units

((1 empty row between units and data))

01/31/2016(\t)14:32:02(\t)14.9(\t)25.3(\t)15.8(\t)25.6

((data repeats for up to 4000 rows))

To recap what I need: 
Import all of the files into individual data frames or a lists of data frames. 
Skip past the header information to the row with "Date" (and possibly delete the two rows following with units and the empty row) leaving me with a row of column names and the data following.

Here's a crude copy of what I have been working on for code. The idea is, after importing all of the files into R, determine the max value for 1-2 columns in each file. Then, export a single file which will have 1 row for each file with 2 columns containing the 2 max values from each file.

```
##list files and create list for data.frames
path <- list.files("Path",pattern = NULL, all.files=FALSE,full.names=TRUE)
files <- list()

##Null list for final data to be extracted to
results <- NULL

##add names to results list (using file name - extension
results$name <- substr(basename(path),1,nchar(basename(Path))-4)

##loop to read in data files and calculate max 
for(i in 1:length(path){
   ##read files
   files[[i]] <- read.delim(path[[i]],header = FALSE, sep = "\t", skip = 18

   ##will have to add code:
     ##"if columnx exists do this; if columny exists do this"
   ##convert 2 columns for calculation to numeric 
   x.x <- as.numeric(as.character(files$columnx))
   x.y <- as.numeric(as.character(files$columny))

   ##will have to add code: 
     ##"if column x exists, do this....if not, "NA"
   ##get max value for 2 specific columns 
   results$max.x <- max(files$columnx)
   results$max.y <- max(files$columny)
}

##add results to data frame 
max <- data.frame(results)

##export to .csv
write.csv(max,file="PATH")
```

I know right now, my code just skips past everything into the data ( max doesn't come until much later in file, so skipping 1 or 2 lines won't hurt me), and it assumes the columns are in the same order in each file. This is horrible practice and gives me some bad results on about 5% of my data points, but I want to do this correctly. My main concern is to get the data into R in a usable format. Then, I can add the other calculations and conversions. I am new to R, and after 2 days of searching, I have not found the help I need already posted to any forum.

Comment: It looks like your approach above is pretty much on track. In order to solve the header information problem, here would be my approach (without all of the details): Read the first 20 lines with the header<-readLines(path[[i]], n=20).  Use grep("^Date", header) to find the row which begins with Date.  Then use "strsplit" to create array of column headers.  From the results of the grep command you can then calculate the starting row of the data and pass that to your read.delim line above.  Good luck

Comment: Thanks, Dave2e. @TJGorrie added your response to his code, so between the two of you, I'm a lot closer than I was!

Comment: Glad to hear there is progress.  If you run into trouble, post a new question with your updated code and some sample data for more help.  The forum likes to see a sample of the starting point and desired endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the structure of the header follows a Line \n Line \n Data we can use a `grep` to find the line number where "mm/dd/yyyy"

As such:

```
system("grep -nr 'mm/dd/yyyy' ran.txt", intern=T)
# ran.txt is an arbitrary text file I created, we will substitute
# 'ran.txt' with path[[i]] later on.
#[1] "6:mm/dd/yyyy\thh:mm:ss\tunits\tunits\tunits\tunits"
```

From this we can then `strsplit` the output into the number before the : and use that argument as the necessary value for `skip`.

```
as.numeric(strsplit(system("grep -nr 'mm/dd/yyyy' ran.txt", intern=T),":")[[1]][1])
# [[1]][1] will specify the first element of the output of strsplit as
# in the output the hh:mm:ss also is split.
# [1] 6
```

As there is an empty row between our called row and the actual data we can add 1 to this and then begin reading the data.

Thusly:

```
##list files and create list for data.frames
path <- list.files("Path",pattern = NULL, all.files=FALSE,full.names=TRUE)
files <- list()

##Null list for final data to be extracted to
results <- NULL

##add names to results list (using file name - extension
results$name <- substr(basename(path),1,nchar(basename(Path))-4)

##loop to read in data files and calculate max 
for(i in 1:length(path)){
##read files
# Calculate the number of rows to skip.
# Using Dave2e's suggestion:
header <-readLines("path[[i]]", n=20)
skip <- grep("^mm/dd/yy", header)
#Add one due to missing line
skip <- skip + 1
files[[i]] <- read.delim(path[[i]],
                         header = FALSE,
                         sep = "\t",
                         skip = skip)

 ##will have to add code:
 ##"if columnx exists do this; if columny exists do this"
 ##convert 2 columns for calculation to numeric 
 x.x <- as.numeric(as.character(files$columnx))
 x.y <- as.numeric(as.character(files$columny))

 ##will have to add code: 
 ##"if column x exists, do this....if not, "NA"
 ##get max value for 2 specific columns 
 results$max.x <- max(files$columnx)
 results$max.y <- max(files$columny)
}

##add results to data frame 
max <- data.frame(results)

##export to .csv
write.csv(max,file="PATH")
```

I think that about covers everything.

Comment: I've updated my code, and I get the following error:
"Error in system(paste("grep -nr 'mm/dd/yyyy'", path[[i]]), intern = T) : 
  'grep' not found"

Here's my code: 
`##loop to read in data files
for (i in 1:length(path)) {
  ##read files
  ##calculate number of rows to skip
  skip <- as.numeric(
            strsplit(
              system(paste("grep -nr \'mm/dd/yyyy\'",path[[i]]),
                     intern = T),":")[[1]][1])
  
  skip <- skip + 1
  files[[i]] <- read.delim(path[[i]],header = FALSE,sep = "\t",skip = skip)
}`

Comment: This was my mistake, I have amended my answer to incorporate @dave2e comment. As this will also do what you want it to do.

Comment: By my mistake, I made an assumption that you were using linux, I presume that you are likely using Windows and as such your `system` will not recognize `grep` unless you have Rtools installed.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Yes, I am using windows. I didn't even think to add that to my question.

Comment: I've done a little work with this, but my boss pulled me off to another project. I'll let you know next week how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would add this here in case it helps someone else with a similar issue. @TJGorrie's solution helped solve my slightly different challenge. I have several .rad files that I need to read in, tag, and merge. The .rad files have headers that start at random rows so I needed a way to find the row with the header. I didn't need to do any additional calculations except create a tag column. Hope this helps someone in the future but thanks @TJGorrie for the awesome answer!

```
##list files and create list for data.frames
path <- list.files(pattern="*.rad")
files <- list()

##loop to read in data files 
for(i in 1:length(path)){

# Using Dave2e's suggestion:
header <-readLines(path[[i]], n=20)
skip <- grep("Sample", header)

#Subtract one row to keep the row with "Sample" in it as the header
skip <- skip - 1

files[[i]] <- read.table(path[[i]],
                         header = TRUE,
                         fill = TRUE,
                         skip = skip,
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Name the newly created file objects the same name as the original file. 
names(files)[i] = gsub(".rad", "", (path[i]))

files[[i]] = na.omit(as.data.frame(files[[i]]))

# Create new column that includes the file name to act as a tag
# when the dfs get merged through rbind

files[[i]]$Tag = names(files)[i]

# bind all the dfs listed in the file into a single df

df = do.call("rbind",
             c(files, make.row.names = FALSE))
}

##export to .csv
write.csv(df,file="PATH.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```